# Center align all contents of bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the logo centered as I would like, but want the `nav` links to be centered as well (next to logo on either side)

what I have so far:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 3;
}
.navbar-left {
  float: none;
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <div id="logo-container">
      <img class="circle-img" id="logo" src="logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </a>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Don't get why it's not yielding my desired layout... also tried wrapping a `div` around the whole `navbar` and center aligning it which did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `float` value to be `none`, then you need to add the `text-center` class to the container, see this for an example:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 3;
}
.nav.navbar-nav {
  float: none !important;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <div id="logo-container">
      <img class="circle-img" id="logo" src="logo.jpg">
    </div>
  </a>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="navbar-collapse-1">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><h1>Link</h1></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```